# TEXTJOIN string only for values matching Todays date

Tags: google-sheets, filter, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

Sample Table

| Date Created (A) | Tracking ID (B) |
| --- | --- |
| 5/12/2022 | '813vz633-7872' |
| 5/12/2022 | '914bz756-7423' |
| 5/12/2022 | '875vu340-5687' |
| 5/11/2022 | '475dv235-6542' |
| 5/11/2022 | '905tg183-9634' |

I want to create a string that looks like this:

filter message.trackingId not in ['813vz633-7872', '914bz756-7423', '875vu340-5687']

This is achieved by using formula:

```
="filter message.trackingId not in ["&TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, B2:B4)&"]"
```

But I want it to automatically pull from Column B only if Column A is todays date

I tried:

```
="filter message.trackingId not in ["&TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(A:A=TODAY(),TEXTJOIN("", TRUE,B2:B))&"]")
```

But that pulls in all values in Column B, not just for todays date

I know I am close, just need a push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, FILTER(B:B, A:A=TODAY()))
```

---

```
="filter message.trackingId not in ["&TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, FILTER(B:B, A:A=TODAY()))&"]"
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm a new account so I don't have enough rep to give you an upvote yet

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`="filter message.trackingId not in ["&TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, FILTER(B:B, A:A=TODAY()))&"]"`

Ironically, the solution includes `FILTER`, which your text portion contains.

(Jinx, player0!)

Comment: Thank you. I'm a new account so I don't have enough rep to give you an upvote yet